# I am trying to install eclipse on Seirra 10.12.4 Have read all threads on this topic to no avail

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

So I have java 1.6.0_65 and it is in my path and works, however it is not a recent enough version to install Eclipse. I have added the new version to my path through the bash_profile and bashrc. when $echo $PATH is ran, it shows java 1.8 but eclipse still only recognizes 1.6. have tried to disable 1.6 only to have java -version reveal nothing. Im not sure what exact information needed to help me solve this 3 day riddle, but ask and I will get it.

Comment: Try hard coding the path to Java 8 In the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate a little? Front end coding for awhile but very new to programming. I tried to find some more info on google but could not.

Comment: Turned the elaboration into an answer. hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have the JDK installed? The JRE is not good enough on macOS.

Comment: Beyond that - any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Greg-449 does Jdk work together with JRE? As in do I need both installed? Or should I remove the JRE and replace with JDK?

Answer (score 0):

One way to **force** eclipse to start with a certain JVM is by turning to the eclipse.ini file.

Example: in my Linux system, I simply extracted the eclipse archive to /opt.

Directly in the root directory, there is an eclipse.ini.
(for me, that would be /opt/eclipse-jee-neon-2-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse.ini). You simply open that ini file in an editor and then you can use `-vm` in order to specify the java binary to use when eclipse starts.

See [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for the official documentation - including a MacOS example.

Comment: Thank you so much GhostCat, we are in business